# React: how to "remember" initial props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am playing around with React and Redux and built a simple todo-app. Now, I want to make a save button for user, that gonna save changes made to the todos if there were any (i.e. changing text). So the save button needs to know somehow if there were any changes made to the todos.

For example, initially we have these todos that are coming from Redux:

```
const todos = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'Learn Redux',
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Learn React',
    }
]
```

But the user made some changes to the todos!

```
const todos = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'Eat a cookie',
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Read a book',
    }
]
```

So my question is, how can I detect those changes?

Comment: Why do you need to know if there were changes? Can you just save them regardless?

Comment: I need to know if there were changes when user clicks the save button. I can set state in the constructor, and then compare state with props that are coming from Redux, but not sure if it's not an anti-pattern.

Comment: are you looking for [https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the point of this is to learn best practices around React + Redux, the best way to do this would be to have your props be the todos coming from your Redux state, and then have your component state be whatever it is currently being mutated to. So in your above example,

Redux state which feeds to component props is

```
const todos = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'Learn Redux',
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Learn React',
    }
]
```

And then component state is

```
const todos = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'Eat a cookie',
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Read a book',
    }
]
```

In your constructor you would do something like (_ is a library like `lodash`):

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { todos: _.clone(props.todos) };
}
```

the component would only ever manipulate `this.state.todos` and then when you are ready to save, you can compare `this.state.todos` to `this.props.todos` to see how things have changed.

Then you dispatch the action to save the todos to your redux state (ex: `save(this.state.todos)`

Your component should be listening to Redux state via a library like `reselect` and its props will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. You could use the constructor to remember initial props by doing something like:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.initialProps = props;
}
```

Since you are using redux you could also handle this in a middleware who's main job is to check and see if the data you are trying to save is different then the value that is kept in the store. [Here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) are the docs for middleware in redux.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch an action to notify the save button whenever you dispatch an action changing the todos. 
Also if your reducer is pure, it will not mutate the previous state, so it is easy to know whether the todos has changed or not. if the object reference is different, it is changed.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using thunk middleware then you may write an action creater like

```
const getTodos = (getState)=>getState().todos;
const saveAction = newTodos=> async(dispatch, getState)=>{
    const initialTodos = getTodos(getState()); 
    await dispatch('SAVE_ACTION', newTodos);
    const finalTodos = getTodos(getState());
    if(initialTodos !== finalTodos){
           dispatch('UPDATE_TODOS_IN_SERVER', finalTodos);
    }
}
```